# How to get first 3 items from Angularfire2 List?

Tags: list, angularfire2

I am trying to get first or last x items from firebase list using AngularFire2,

```
return this.af.database.list('classes/class-001').takeLast(3);
```

but I get nothing even with subscribe on the above.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
return = af.database.list('classes/class-001', {
  query: {
    limitToLast: 3,
  }
});
```